# Expansion tile trailing icon updates all in list on interaction with one tile. How can I only change the icon for the expanded tile?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

How do I make it so that the icon will only update for the tile that was clicked? Right now, the behavior is that *all* icons update when clicking on one tile.

Here is the code (trimmed to only include relevant parts):

```
Column(children: List.generate(
    filteredFAQ.length,
    (index) => Column(
        children: [
            if(index > 0) {
                Container(
                    child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            ExpansionTile(
                            trailing: SvgPicture.string(
                                isQuestionClicked
                                    ? addPayeeArrowUp
                                    : rightArrow,
                                color: primary,
                              ),
                              onExpansionChanged:
                                  (bool expanded) {
                                setState(() {
                                  isQuestionClicked = expanded;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                        ],
                    )
                )
            }
        ]
    )
),);
```

here are screenshots of the behavior:

[image: beforeClickingOneTile]

[[image: afterClickingOneTile][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la7iW.png)

I used the in built onExpansionChange of the ExpansionTile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only change the icon of the expanded tile, you can use this approach:

create a `Map`:

```
Map<int, bool> state = {};
```

and use it accordingly in your `ExpansionTile` to check whether it's selected, if the value is `true` or `false`:

```dart
 List.generate(6, (index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
            trailing: state[index] ?? false
                ? Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up)
                : Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onExpansionChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                state[index] = value;
              });
            },
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
```

---

Complete runnable example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  Map<int, bool> state = {};

  bool isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children:
            // generate 6 ExpansionTiles
            List.generate(6, (index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
            trailing: state[index] ?? false
                ? Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up)
                : Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            onExpansionChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                state[index] = value;
              });
            },
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage each childrens state separatory.
I think it's best to manage them in filteredFAQ by adding

```
bool isExpanded
```

property there. but you can achive by manage them as separated property like

```
final items = List<bool>.generate(filteredFAQ.length, (index) => false);
```

and change their state when they're expanded

```
items[index] = !items[index]
```

here's a sample complete code

```
Column(children: List.generate(
    filteredFAQ.length,
    (index) => Column(
        children: [
            if(index > 0) {
                Container(
                    child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            ExpansionTile(
                            trailing: SvgPicture.string(
                                items[index]
                                    ? addPayeeArrowUp
                                    : rightArrow,
                                color: primary,
                              ),
                              onExpansionChanged:
                                  (bool expanded) {
                                setState(() {
                                  items[index] = !items[index];
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                        ],
                    )
                )
            }
        ]
    )
),);
```

And don't forget to initalize items at where you initialize filteredFAQ

If you provide a whole code in the widget I can complete it if you need more information