# How can I only check one checkbox at time?

Tags: flutter

How can I select/check only one checkbox to be checked at time?

[image]

And below is my code

```
Container(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
            Checkbox(
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                value: isChecked,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                        isChecked = value;
                        // ignore: unnecessary_statements
                        passData(certId);
                    });
                },
            ),
        ],
    )),
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Option1 - Using a `map` to maintain the state

Create a map:

```dart
final Map<int, bool> _state = {};
```

then, check if the value for that index is `true`/`false`:

```dart
return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return CheckboxListTile(
        value: _state[index] ?? false,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _state[index] = value!;
          });
        },
        title: Text(_data[index].text),
      );
    });
```

#### Option 2 - using a model:

```dart
class CheckBoxModel {
  bool isChecked = false;
  String text = "";
  CheckBoxModel({required this.isChecked, required this.text});
}
```

and then, generate a List of 30 widgets:

```dart
final _data = List.generate(
    30, (index) => CheckBoxModel(isChecked: false, text: "Item $index"));
```

Now, use a `ListView.builder` and based on the `index`, to update the corresponding value:

```dart
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return CheckboxListTile(
        value: _data[index].isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _data[index].isChecked = value!;
          });
        },
        title: Text(_data[index].text),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

##### See also

[Expansion tile trailing icon updates all in list on interaction with one tile. How can I only change the icon for the expanded tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74857851/expansion-tile-trailing-icon-updates-all-in-list-on-interaction-with-one-tile-h/74857943#74857943)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I've use option 1 and it return this error
`Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#6a7d2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.`

Comment: I'm using flutter version 2.2.3

Comment: @Fash Well, that's a completely _separate_ problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801201/flutter-renderbox-was-not-laid-out to fix it

Comment: I've accepted your answer... sorry take time

Comment: I've fix error `child.hasSize` and when I using your both option 1 and 2... index always returns 0

Comment: `I/flutter (11598): true
I/flutter (11598): 0
I/flutter (11598): true
I/flutter (11598): 0
I/flutter (11598): true
I/flutter (11598): 0`